# Dar mais de um evento para uma janela

Tags: java, swing

Então, eu criei uma janela em java, mas eu preciso atribuir um evento diferente a mesma dependendo da ocasião em que ela ser chamada. E o problema é, não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Há um modo de fazer?

Janela: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só ter um evento diferente por instância da janela dependendo de onde a instância é criada. Qual a dificuldade? Inclua o que está tentando.

Comment: Como você identifica esse evento?